# How to make a View response downloadable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an XML file which is rendered from a template.

The code:

```
public function createXml($id)
{
    $order = Order::with('orderLines.bike.gallery')->with('orderLines.product')->with('orderLines.accu')->find($id);
    $debtor = User::find($order->user_id);

    return response()->view('ordersxml.order-template',compact('order','debtor'))->header('Content-Type','text/xml');
}
```

I want people to automatically download the .xml file. How do I do this? Do I need to save it for this to work? As it it now, it just returns the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this header before send the response to user and try again:

`Content-disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.xml"`

This header will force browser to download your xml.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return response()->view('ordersxml.order-template',compact('order','debtor'))->header('Content-Type','text/xml');
```

try:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);

return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);

return response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Yes, you need to save it for this to work, as path is required in above functions.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-downloads)